# is there anyway to start scrolling slowly to go end of div content in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there any way to scroll div contend slowly and go to end of page .On button click I go to end page quickly.But it is possible to go slowly ?

I used this on button click .

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
```

Comment: why don't you try combination of `.animate()`.?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/YUhgF/6/ ..here is my latest fiddle can we add iscroll library in div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery `animate` for this purpose:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight }, 1000);
```

The `1000` value here is the timer for this animation, the greater the value, the slower it animates/scrolls.

Comment: @Rohit check this fiddle for supporting kayen's answer. http://jsfiddle.net/ds345/thpUD/

Comment: Here is my latest fiddle .can we add iscroll library here ?http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/YUhgF/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `.animate` as i suggested in comment.

**Sample**

```
$("a[href='#bottom']").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
  return false;
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h4ZQR/)

Comment: But it also to fast .I need slowly -2.Because I need to check on android tab .Is android tab have scrolling issue or not:(